# Changing app's price to free, while implementing in-app items

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app

I work on a new version of my application already available on the Store.
For the moment this is a paid app.
I want to change my business model and set the app price to free with the possibility for new users to unlock some features by purchasing an in-app.

I already understand how to add the in-app.
I don't know how to manage users that have already bought the app!
What is the good way to detect / unlock an in-app for my previous users when they will update the app?

Thanks

François

Comment: I asked the same question to the google support: "there isn't currently an easy way to allow users that have previously purchased the app to buy in-app products. These users might have to purchase the in-app items like all other users. We apologize for any inconvenience this may cause."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from Google support:

"there isn't currently an easy way to allow users that have previously purchased the app to buy in-app products. These users might have to purchase the in-app items like all other users. We apologize for any inconvenience this may cause."

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in three steps:

1. Publish a new release of the paid app that includes a feature that sets a `SharedPreference` (or any other way) to mark the fact this one was paid
2. While users are upgrading to the new version, prepare the future free release in a way it checks whether the `SharedPreference` described in 1. exists. Unlock features accordingly and keep them locked for non-paid instances
3. Publish this new version and switch to the free business model. The `SharedPreference` will survive the upgrade.

This would work for most users but this is not perfect though: users who will have either

- uninstalled/reinstalled the app (even the new free version)
- installed the app on a new device (even the new free version)
- kept a former version of the paid app that doesn't set the `SharedPreference`

would not benefit from the unlock.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Shlublu. I was also thinking about that solution but exactly because of these 3 points i can't implement them. I would not miss any user. Is there a way to know the first installed version of an application?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, unless the app generates some content you could track and use to determine its version. According to your stats, would that represent a lot of users? (knowing that those who don't update at all won't miss any locked content as will still be using the paid app)